# how to calculate sum of goods including previous date

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Please help to solve the issue.

Can't make the request to work properly,
In order to get the quantity of goods in the store, I need to deduct sum of all products from all suppliers from the amount of goods sold,
and then add the difference to the difference of the previous day - it will be the remainder in stock. The problem is with the last condition..

What I've got now:
Q1 - Calculates the sum of all products from all suppliers for a particular date. (income)
Q2 - Calculates the amount of goods sold for a particular date. (spending)
Store_1 - The amount of goods sold is deducted from the sum of all products from all suppliers. (difference)
Store_2 - difference + difference for the previous day. But these figures are not calculated correctly, except the first line.  (remainder in store)
How to get the correct data? **WHERE condition(particular date – 1 day?)**

Date is stored in seconds, that is why I used date converter .

```
SELECT Q1.Dat, Q1.Goods AS Q1, Q2.Goods AS Q2, Q1.Goods - Q2.Goods  AS Store_1,
(CASE WHEN Q1.Dat <= '2013.01.01' THEN Q1.Goods - Q2.Goods + 330016
ELSE (Q1.Goods - Q2.Goods) + (SELECT SUM (Q1.Goods - Q2.Goods)+330016 FROM Q1, Q2
WHERE particular date – 1 day) END ) AS Store_2

FROM
    (SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(s, nb.TEreport.data, 25568), 102) AS Dat, 
    SUM(nb.TEreport.goods) AS Goods
    FROM nb.TEreport INNER JOIN nb.TEprovider ON nb.TEreport.id_provider = nb.TEprovider.id
    WHERE (LEFT(nb.TEprovider.name, 10) != 'FROM STORE') 
    AND (CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(s, nb.TEreport.data, 25568), 102) <= CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 102))
    AND CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(s, nb.TEreport.data, 25568), 102) >= '2013.01.01'
    GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(s, nb.TEreport.data, 25568), 102)
    ORDER BY Dat ) Q1 --income
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(s, nb.TEreport.data, 25568), 102) AS Dat, 
    SUM(nb.TEreport.goods) AS Goods
    FROM nb.TEreport INNER JOIN nb.TEway ON nb.TEreport.id_way = nb.TEway.id
    WHERE (SUBSTRING(nb.TEway.name, 5, 8) != 'TO STORE') 
    AND (CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(s, nb.TEreport.data, 25568), 102) <= CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 102))
    AND CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(s, nb.TEreport.data, 25568), 102) >= '2013.01.01'
    GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(s, nb.TEreport.data, 25568), 102)
    ORDER BY Dat ) Q2 --spending
ON Q1.Dat = Q2.Dat
ORDER BY Q1.Dat
```

Tried to use **CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(s, nb.TEreport.data, 25567), 102)** where 25567 is previous date

```
 (CASE WHEN Q1.Dat <= '2013.01.01' THEN Q1.Goods - Q2.Goods + 330016
    ELSE (Q1.Goods - Q2.Goods) + (SELECT SUM (Q1.Goods - Q2.Goods)+330016 FROM Q1, Q2
    WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(s, nb.TEreport.data, 25567), 102) ) END ) AS Store_2
```

But I have an error message: Invalid object name 'Q1', invalid object name 'Q2'

Comment: It looks like you haven't defined a column alias for Dat in either Q1 or Q2 joins. Presumely this is: CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(s, nb.TEreport.data, 25568)?

Answer (score 0):

`Q1` and `Q2` are derived tables and you can't reference them from a correlated subquery (which is what your `(SELECT SUM  (Q1.Goods - Q2.Goods)+330016 ...)` thing is), because those are .

An easy solution in this case would be to rewrite `Q1` and `Q2` as CTEs. That way they would act as "local views", which would allow you to reference those subqueries multiple times.

So, here you go:

```
WITH Q1 AS (
  SELECT ...      -- your Q1 subquery
),
Q2 AS (
  SELECT ...      -- your Q2 subquery
)
SELECT ...        -- same as before but Q1 and Q2 are now valid
                  -- for referencing in other subqueries

FROM Q1           -- just "Q1" and "Q2" instead of the subqueries
INNER JOIN Q2

ON ...            -- the rest of your query as before
;
```

Comment: I use MS SQL Server 2008 R2, but WITH doesn't work here. What is the problem?

Comment: Elaborating on the *doesn't work* bit might help. A wild guess: there's a statement before `WITH` that is not delimited with a `;`.